# traer los datos de un select y ponerlos en un input

Tags: javascript, ajax, phpmyadmin

Hola buen día a todos tengo una base de datos que tiene 3 columnas [id][cliente][precio] se cargan los datos del cliente en un select y me gustaria que al seleccionar el cliente en el select el dato de precio se cargue en un input

de antemano gracias

```js
// Cada vez que cambie el select
$("#seleccionarCliente").change(function(){
  // a la variable x le asigno el value del select con id="seleccionarCliente"
  var x = $('#seleccionarCliente').val();
  // le asigno el valor de x al input con id="cdCliente"
  $('#cdCliente').val(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
    <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>
        <option  value="">Seleccionar cliente</option>
        <!--Ejemplos para mostrar el resultado, los puedes eliminar-->
        <option value="1">Cliente 1</option>
        <option value="2">Cliente 2</option>
        <?php
            $item = null;
            $valor = null;
            $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);
            foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) :?>
                <option value="<?= $value['id']; ?>"><?= $value['nombre']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;
        ?>
    </select>
    <!-- cambiar type text por hidden -->
    <input type="text" id="cdCliente" name="cdCliente" >
</div>
</div>
```

este es el código que tenia originalmente pero necesito traer de la base de datos de la columna precio y colocarlo en el input id="cdCliente" al seleccionar el cliente en el option

Comment: Haz un `console.log()` de la respuesta del ajax

Comment: Como es que mandas los datos de `ajax/productos.ajax.php`, si los mandas como `JSON` necesitas parsear ese json a JS con la función `JSON.parse()`, puedes poner tu código PHP `ajax/productos.ajax.php` para orientarnos más.

Comment: Vick, no es necesario que que los parsee a un Json, ya que en el método esta indicando que las respuesta de la petición ajax va a ser de tipo json

dataType:"json",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aclarar no trabajo en php, pero si tengo experiencia en ajax y jquery, si lo que quieres es dejar uno de los datos en un input, lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: context + "login.html",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ({rutUsuario: rutUsuario, password: password}),
            success: function (resultado) {
                if (resultado.codigo === "OK") {
                        $.each(resultado.listaLocales, function (i, option) {
                            $(".row  select").append('<option value="' + option.idLocal + '">' + option.alias + '</option>');
                        });
                        // INICIO En este punto seteas los valores en un input
                        $("#cdCliente").val(option.idLocal)
                        // FIN de ejemplo
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = context + resultado.goToUrl;
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#modalError").click();
                }
            }
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.status === 500) {
                    modal.cerrarCargando();
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                    window.location.href = context;
                } else if (xhr.status === 401) {
                    window.location.href = context;
                } else {
                    modal.cerrarCargando();
                }
            }
        });
```

este es un ejemplo realizado en java pero agregue la linea de como setear un valor en el input.

salufos

Comment: gracias por tus aportaciones